# IntelliJ Idea (community) scan for errors in closed files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

What do I have to do to make Idea find errors in non-opened files?

Two example scenarios for better idea what's on my mind:

1. Adding new module with existing sources. Module is loaded, backround scan task is finished and all files look fine. Until opened. Idea will mark the file as broken and realize for example compile error until the file is opened.
2. Simple project, classes A and B. In class B, method A.foo() is called. Everithing is find. File (class B is closed) when I delete foo method from class A. Idea won't realize that class B contains compile error until I open the B class.

Any Idea how to fix that? For example NetBeans handles such situations like expected.

Answer (score 2):

The background code analyzer in IntelliJ IDEA works only on files opened in the editor. To see the errors in all files, just compile the project.

If you prefer, you can enable automatic background compilation in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler.

Comment: Most similar option I found is "Make project automaticaly" and that did not solve example 2.

Answer (score 0):

> when I delete foo method from class A. Idea won't realize that class B contains compile error until I open the B class.

IntelliJ IDEA has a strong *preventative over reactive* problem solving philosophy. In other words, you should use the tools and refactoring actions in IDEA to prevent your code from getting into a non-compilable state rather than using the code analysis to later find and react to the problem.

In this case, if you use the "safe delete" refactoring action to delete the `A.foo()` method, IDEA will warn you that it is unsafe to delete it because of its use in Class B. You should then resolve that prior to deleting the method. To use safe delete, put your cursor on the method name and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> on Mac). It is also available in the refactor menu (Refactor > Safe Delete). When making other changes, use the other refactoring tools such as rename, change signature, move, etc.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I share your view but it doesn't answer my question and does not necessarilly mean that what I'm looking for could not be helpful. Other IDEs can do this.

Comment: Sorry... I meant for my implied answer to be that IntelliJ IDEA can not do this. Yole, who is a Principal Engineer at JetBrains and was the tech lead for IntelliJ IDEA for many many years, also indicated such in his answer.